# vuejs render <svg> tag on component

Tags: vue.js, svg

I'm looking for how to render  to component on vuejs project.

I'm using https://github.com/juliuste/parliament-svg to create chart.

here is my code

```
created() {
    let parties = {
      linke: {
        seats: 64,
        colour: "#a08"
      },
      spd: {
        seats: 193,
        colour: "#e02"
      },
      gruene: {
        seats: 63,
        colour: "#0b2"
      },
      union: {
        seats: 311,
        colour: "#333"
      }
    };
    const svg = parliamentSVG(parties, true);
    var stringify = require("virtual-dom-stringify");
    this.parliamentSVG = stringify(svg);
  }
```

which return

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-20.487130703115444,-20.487130703115444,40.97426140623089,20.97426140623089"><circle cx="-20" r="0.38970456249235585" fill="#a08" class="linke"></circle><circle cx="-19.9766445366" cy="-0.9662675905" r="0.38970456249235585" fill="#a08" class="linke"></circle><circle cx="-19.9066326944" cy="-1.9302784183" r="0.38970456249235585" fill="#a08" class="linke"></circle><circle cx="-19.790127989" cy="-2.8897809914" r="0.38970456249235585" fill="#a08" class="linke"></circle><circle cx="-19.6274025228" cy="-3.8425343471" r="0.38970456249235585" fill="#a08" class="linke"></circle><circle cx="-19.4188363485" cy="-4.7863132858" r="0.38970456249235585" fill="#a08" class="linke"></circle><circle cx="-19.1649165822" cy="-5.718913568" r="0.38970456249235585" fill="#e02" class="spd"></circle><circle cx="-18.8662362652" cy="-6.6381570626" r="0.38970456249235585" fill="#e02" class="spd"></circle><circle cx="-18.5234929792" cy="-7.5418968338" r="0.38970456249235585" fill="#e02" class="spd"></circle><circle cx="-18.137487217" cy="-8.4280221555" r="0.38970456249235585" fill="#e02" class="spd"></circle><circle cx="-17.7091205131" ....
```

in `<div>{{parliamentSVG}}</div>`

I'm looking the way to render as a graph.

Comment: I don't quite understand.  What exactly isn't working?  Could you add more detail to your question?

Comment: perhaps you mean that it displays the html instead of interpreting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML):

> The double mustaches interprets the data as plain text, not HTML. In order to output real HTML, you will need to use the `v-html` directive.

---

In your case:

```
<div v-html="parliamentSVG"></div>
```